# How to pass a variable from local flask app to remote flask app

Tags: python, flask

I have two flask files. One is `home.py` and the other is `remote.py`.

The `remote.py` will be on another computer in LAN which acts as a server.  The `home.py` will be in my computer.

In the `home.py`, i pass the url for accessing the `remote.py` file and if the url gets accessed,the `home.py` executes the route for adding two numbers and store the result in `c` variable and sent `c`  to the remote.py file.

In `remote.py` file, I have a route for  getting `c` value from the home  system and store it in a `get_c` variable.

Here's the Sample Code i tried:

home.py

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/sum_value_pass', methods=['POST'])
def sum_value_pass():
    try:
        url = '192.168.1.3:5001/sum_value_get'
        if url accessed:
            a = 4
            b = 4

            c = a + b
            print(c)
            # send c value to remote system
    except:
        print("URL offline")
if __name__ == '__main__':

    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5002)
```

remote.py

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/sum_value_get', methods=['POST'])
def sum_value_get():
    get_c = []
    print(get_c)
    # get c from home system not yet written



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='192.168.1.3', port=5001)
```

This is what i tried. I don't know how to pass variable between two flask app. Help me with some solutions to make it possible.

Comment: How are you attempting to make a request to the server from the home script? You will need to either use the built in urllib or a library such as requests. To make a POST request you can do `requests.post(url, data={'c': c})`. In the route on the server, you can use `get_c = request.form['c']`

Comment: Also, could you elaborate on "In the home.py, i pass the url for accessing the remote.py file and if the url gets accessed..."? I'm not sure I understand what exactly the goal is. Do you want to access a url on the home server, which in turn sends `c` to the remote server? If so, that's what I attempted to answer in the first comment.

Answer (score -1):

In your remote.py, does the method supported by just `GET` and not `POST`

```
@app.route('/sum_value_get', methods=['GET'])
def sum_value_get():
    get_c = []
    print(get_c)
    # get c from home system not yet written
```

This would indeed be the correct way to go about it.

If you are needing help with sending get and post requests form your server(s),

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/get-post-requests-using-python/ might be a good starting point